# Audio file is not playing in html 5

Tags: html

I added a audio file in html 5 with audio controls attributes. It works the first time I run the code. After a while when I add base tag into head tag, the audio won't play. And when I removed that base tag, the audio file plays.. Please tell me why this happens ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html> 
    <head> 
      <base href="https://www.goole.com"; target="_blank"><!--If i don't write this line the audio file will play--> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
      <h3> Adding a audio file </h3> 
      <a href="http://google.com">Go to goole</a> 
      <audio controls> 
        <source src="moner.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> 
        Your browser does not support the audio element. 
      </audio> 
      <p>
        <strong>Note:</strong> The audio tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Please post your code, we cannot guess what is happening without it...

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="https://www.goole.com" target="_blank"><!--If i don't write this line the audio file will play-->
</head>
<body>
<h3> Adding a audio file </h3>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Go to goole</a>
<audio controls>
 
  <source src="moner.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The audio tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>

Comment: please include your last comment in the question

Comment: the base tag will mean that it tries to fetch the file from `https://www.goole.com/moner.mp3`. It alters the base for all relative URLs in a document. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) Presumably this file doesn't exist (you can check your network tab in the browser for what happens when it tries to request this URL, if you don't get a 200 status for that file then it didn't download). Why did you need a base tag anyway?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. I know that google chrome supports the HTML5<audio> tag.But it doesn't working

Comment: @AsadulIslam I assume that was related to my earlier comment. Sorry, I was mistaken. I thought it was an error message, not some text you wrote (it would be much clearer if you posted the code inside your question as Daniele mentioned). I have amended it to focus on what is probably the real issue.

Comment: Also the `;` in your base tag is a syntax error.

Comment: base tag is not necessary for my code. I just want to see the use of base tag. Thank you @Adyson .Probably I understand what you want to say.I am sorry for not including my code earlier in my question.This was my first question.

Comment: @AsadulIslam no problem. I have written this explanation up as an answer, I would be grateful if you would "accept" the answer, so future readers can understand clearly the solution to the question. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `<base>` tag alters the base URL which is prepended to all relative URLs in a document (the default base would be the domain from which the page was served).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base for more detail.

Since your audio tag's "src" contains a relative URL (i.e. one without an explicit protocol or domain specified), adding this tag to your code will mean that it tries to fetch the MP3 file from this URL: `https://www.goole.com/moner.mp3`

Presumably in your case this file doesn't exist, which is why the audio doesn't play.

Comment: This is more specific .Thank you@ADyson

Comment: No problem. Please remember to "accept" the answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me with and without the `base` tag in the html.

[CodePen w/o Tag](https://codepen.io/DeathCamel57/pen/gXzrNz)

[CodePen with Tag](https://codepen.io/DeathCamel57/pen/jaxrbj)

I'm using

```
Vivaldi 1.11.917.43 (Stable channel) (64-bit)
Revision    6171cfeb79410505bfdd70a1434a4587da29614e-
OS  Linux
JavaScript  V8 6.0.286.54
Flash   27.0.0.187 /home/deathcamel57/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/27.0.0.187/libpepflashplayer.so
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.105 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.92.917.43
```

Works on Firefox too.
[image: Firefox Version]

Also works on Google Chrome

```
Google Chrome
Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Comment: your example is invalid because the "src" of your audio uses an absolute URL. The `<base>` tag only impacts on relative URLs such as the one the OP is using. Therefore this does not reproduce or resolve the issue at all. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base